# how to pass parameter in mssql sever with slashes in between

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have created the procedure with 3 parameters, facing the problem with a parameter having slashes and space in between. getting the error at the 3rd parameter stating that syntax error at 360.

```
CREATE PROC getMaxModelVersionNumber( @PassedTableName as NVarchar(255) , @modelName as NVarchar(255), @modelViewName as NVarchar(255) ) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ActualTableName AS NVarchar(255)

SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = ' SELECT MAX(modelVersionNumber) FROM ' + @ActualTableName+
      ' WHERE modelName=' + @modelName +  ' AND modelViewName='  + @modelViewName+ ';'

    EXEC(@SQL)
END


EXEC getMaxModelVersionNumber @PassedTableName = 'Läufe', @modelName = 'D1088_x_XX-_M_00_0000_00_x.rvt ', @modelViewName = 'BIM 360 // Design Model // IFC Export // Navisworks'
```

Getting this error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near '360'.
```

Comment: Please share more details because all works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26ef5420b7f1cf0091c90c0e473c3743

Comment: FYI, object names have a max length of 128 characters, as they use the `sysname` datatype for their names (a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`), so you're better off using `sysname` for the parameter instead of `nvarchar(255)` (as the last 127 characters would be effectively pointless). I also recommend passing the schema name as a parameter; even if you do default it to `N'dbo'` when it's omitted.

Comment: Can I pass 3 parameters directly to the SQL query rather than just selecting the table name from the information schema using QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the constant values using parameters:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = '
SELECT MAX(modelVersionNumber)
FROM ' + @ActualTableName + '
WHERE modelName = @modelName AND modelViewName = @modelViewName';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@modelName NVarchar(255), @modelViewName NVarchar(255)',
                   @modelName=@modelName, @modelViewName=@modelViewName;
```

This passes in the parameter values as parameter values.  You cannot pass in the table name as a parameter, but you can pass in constants.

Notes:

- You should probably use `quotename()` for the table name.  That is just a best practice when passing in identifiers.
- You can also munge the query string by adding in single quotes.  I don't recommend that approach however.

Comment: My bad, I noticed the OP grabs it in `INFORMAITON_SCHEMA` and quotes. +1

Comment: There was a typographical error in the SQL, that i fixed in there, @masterstack . There was a missing single quote (`'`) after `+ @ActualTableName + `. Once you add that, it's valid SQL.

Comment: Can I pass 3 parameters directly to the SQL query rather than just selecting the table name from the information schema using QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )?

Comment: @masterstack . . . No.  As the answer specifies, you cannot pass in the table name -- or any other identifier, SQL keyword, function name, or operator.  Only constants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for the answer, so every time when I need a table name I have to select the table name from the information schema, right?

Comment: @masterstack . . . No.  You can just use `quotename()` to construct the query with the passed in name.  However, as Larnu points out, it is safer to check that the table really exists.  That is very good insurance against SQL injection attacks.