# How to create stored procedure sql server to update column attribute with where condition? how to solve ` =` in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to use `=` sign with where condition.

The actual query want to execute as -

```
UPDATE {table_name} SET new_units = {new} WHERE [{frm_name}] = '{old_val}'
```

new_units, frm_name are column. whereas new and old_val are both strings values

Tried to create the same procedure like this (similar concept)-

[how to pass parameter in mssql sever with slashes in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64153956/how-to-pass-parameter-in-mssql-sever-with-slashes-in-between)

```
CREATE PROC updateTable( @PassedTableName as NVarchar(255) , @new as NVarchar(255), @frm_name as NVarchar(255), @old_val as NVarchar(255) ) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ActualTableName AS NVarchar(255)

SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @sql = '
UPDATE ' + @ActualTableName + '
SET new_units =  @new WHERE frm_name=@frm_name' + '=' + 'old_val=@old_val';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@new NVarchar(255), @frm_name NVarchar(255), @old_val NVarchar(255)',
                   @new =@new, @frm_name=@frm_name, @old_val=@old_val;
END
```

Try to execute the procedure -

```
EXEC updateTable  @PassedTableName='PlanData', @new='test',  @frm_name='type',  @old_val= 'versions'
```

Getting correct results with the following results -

```
UPDATE PlanData SET new_units = 'test' WHERE type= 'versions';
```

Comment: This has a bad code smell. A generic procedure to update a specific column in any table - but your logic relies on the use of hard-coded column names. The column name `new_units` implies a numeric value but you use a string to pass in both the old and new values. And it seems unlikely `frm_name` is the primary key.

Comment: @SMor No,  `new_units` implies the string value only where its actually column name

Comment: So you have a few tables that all of them have columns named `new_units`, `frm_name` and `old_val`?

Comment: @ATC correct. Does it matter how many tables?

Comment: No, but it might be a code smell as SMor wrote. If all these tables describe the same entity, then there should be only one table. Usually when you see things like (Just an example) `tblOrders_2018`, `tblOrders_2019` and `tblOrders_2020` it should be just `tblOrders` and the year should be reflected as a column in that table

Comment: @ATC all are columns of the same table. new_units, frm_name are column. whereas new and old_val are both strings values

Comment: If it's one table, why use dynamic sql to begin with? If it's multiple tables, you might want to rethink your database design.

Comment: I want to convert the query into a stored procedure if I need a column from one or more tables in the future, then I will add do that.

Answer (score 1):

A few things.  The procedure is declared as if it's a function, i.e. the parameters are in parentheses.  Also, it appears the assignment of the variable @sql was not properly concatenating the string together.  Also, when the procedure is executed the dynamic SQL contains the input parameters which have already been concatenated into the string so no need to further parameterize.  It could be something like this

```
CREATE PROC updateTable
  @PassedTableName  NVarchar(255),
  @new              NVarchar(255),
  @frm_name         NVarchar(255),
  @old_val          NVarchar(255) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ActualTableName AS NVarchar(255);

SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName;

 DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
 SELECT @sql = N'UPDATE ' + @ActualTableName + 
               N' SET new_units = @new' + 
               N' WHERE frm_name = @frm_name and old_val=@old_val;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@new NVarchar(255), @frm_name NVarchar(255), @old_val NVarchar(255)',
                   @new=@new, @frm_name=@frm_name, @old_val=@old_val;
END
```

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64153956/how-to-pass-parameter-in-mssql-sever-with-slashes-in-between)    Have you checked this?  what do with a parameter with spaces? and after where condition we have '=' not AND

Comment: UPDATE {table_name} SET new_units = {new} WHERE [{frm_name}] = '{old_val}'

Comment: It's updated.  What happens when you run the sql as a single string?  It needs dynamic parameterization in order to pass a string with slashes in between?

Comment: Where is the @frm_name? before the @old_val

Comment: Updated please review

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `and`, not `=`:

```
UPDATE ' + @ActualTableName + '
    SET new_units = @new
    WHERE frm_name=@frm_name and old_val=@old_val';
```

Comment: This is the actual query want to convert to stored proc

UPDATE {table_name} SET new_units = {new} WHERE [{frm_name}] = '{old_val}'

Comment: I want = only. Both  [{frm_name}] = '{old_val}' are as string input